# Is there any problem with scalability if uniqueidentifier is used as a primary key?

Tags: asp.net

The ASP.net membership provider user database uses `uniqueidentifier` as a primary key. Could this cause any problem with scalability for potentially millions of users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a GUID as primary (and thus by default clustering) key in SQL Server is a recipe for really bad performance. Due to the randomness of the GUIDs, they'll lead to a heavy clustered index fragmentation on your table. If you have more than a few entries, you'll have to constantly rebuild that clustered index to get even halfway decent performance.

So yes - I think using a GUID as your primary/clustered key in any database table of more than a few hundred entries is a really bad idea - and as the example shows, even certain Microsoft teams don't seem to care about that and come up with bad designs.

Read more about the topic in the excellent series of blog post by Kimberly Tripp - the Queen of Indexing has great insights into why this is a horribly bad idea, and gives more pointers as to what would make a good clustered key:

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)

Comment: and what is the solution?Not ues asp.net membership?

Comment: No, but if you really anticipate having millions of users, I would create an additional `UserID INT IDENTITY` column and make **that** the clustered key on your user table (same with the role table etc). That way, you would leave the logical constructs (GUID as primary key) alone, but you would also get around the horrible performance of GUIDs as clustering keys

Comment: @marc_s: Not sure how long it's been like this, but the clustered index on the membership tables is not the uniqueidentifier field. For example, on the users table the PK is non-clustered, and the clustered index is on ApplicationId along with the Username.

Answer (score 0):

Using a uniqueidentifier field means that for every user you store 16 bytes for each user. If it were an integer that would be 4 bytes.

When it comes to millions of records, this impacts on storage and amount of required IO (disk and network), both for the field itself and any index defined on it and any foreign keys referencing it.

In terms of how they perform internally in SQL Server (joins, indexing and foreign keys), it will not impact performance.

In short, yes, it can have an impact on performance.

Comment: plus the absolute randomness of GUID's causes massive table/index fragmentation and thus kills performance big time...

Comment: Fragmentation can be dealt with via Guid.Comb which attempts to sequentially generate GUID's